# Does a Stateless Functional Component equal to a Component which just has a render method?

Tags: reactjs

Like the question above:

#### Stateless Functional Component:

```
const Comments = props => {
    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}
```

#### Component which just has a render method:

```
class Comments extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
```

What's the **essence** of the two different way? Are they the same and all stateless?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, here's the short breakdown:

1. You will have to use ES6 classes (`class MyClass extends Component {}`) or (`React.createClass()`) if:

   - you **need access to the [lifecycle methods of your component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods)**  (most frequently used ones are `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`. Basically it means you depend on the library to call some functions for you for each instance of your component, depending on what happens in your app.
   - your component has **direct access to your store** and thus **holds state** (also frequently referred to as **smart components** or **containers**). Some people would argue that tying the component the store doesn't necessarily mean it's a 'smart' component. Maybe it just works with props and doesn't really have an internal state of it's own.
2. If your component simply takes in props and renders them on the page, then you are dealing with a **stateless component** (also frequently referred to as **dumb components** or **presentational components**). Since the component does nothing on it's own other than showing what it's supposed to show and everything is handed to it using props one can use a pure function to represent it. This can be as simple as your example:

   ```
   const Comments = props => {
       return (
           <div></div>
       );
   }
   ```

They obviously do not have to be as simple and can be more complex: hold children, consume only part of the props and pass on some of them to the children, pass on props of it's own etc.

If you want truly pure functional components it is advisable that you read up on **[ES6 Features](http://es6-features.org/)** and get a good handle on those.

Here's a **[great article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.6mrracj51)** (probably one of the best on the topic that has been shared around a lot) from Dan Abramov that can hopefully clear up any confusion.

If your component does nothing more than have a render function and show some content (i.e it is **stateless**), it is advisable that you use a functional component. Everywhere possible. They are more light-weight and carry less of a footprint that heavier classes do. You can find, which I believe to be, [the best article on how to write optimal ES6 React components right here](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/optimize-es6-output-size-performance-ninja-tricks-included-d4fc2d313f66#.j4m8w3wgm) - It's by Grgur Grisogono, one of the top figures on the scene.

Comment: Ok, what if i use `class Comments extends Component` and access its refs attribution? Does that being considered a stateful component? Or that must be an access to store/state?

Comment: If you would want to use `refs`, you would (currently) be forced to use an actual class, even if it doesn't do anything that would justify it being an actual class. Unless you'd want to circumvent encapsulation and start hackin' it, which I do not recommend. I don't think anyone would. You can find a [pretty good discussion on this topic here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936)